# Why does google sign-in and email sign-in of firebase authentication is not merging/linking itself?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-signin

In my web application where I am using Firebase Aauthentication, I have provided both the option of Google sign-in and email password sign-in. Both were working fine until yesterday(21-oct-2023)

My users were able to sign up using email(let's say abcd@gmail.com) and password and sign in with their credentials and when they tried to sign-in with Google using the same Google email(abcd@gmail.com) firebase was somehow able to merge those accounts automatically without deleting my email/password credentials.

Now what happens is that when I try to sign in with Google using `abcd@gmail.com` it just overrides the email-password credentials because when I try to use email-password authentication it throws me this error code `auth/wrong-password`.

Here is the image when firebase just use to merge my account but it's not happening now. You can see the Aug 5, 2023 account where google and email logo is showing
[image]

Here is the some of my authentication code.

**Sign-up**

```
const signUpWithEmailAndPassword = async (email, password) => {
        try {
            const authInstance = getAuth();
            return await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                authInstance,
                email,
                password
            );
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('err', err);
            if (err.code === 'auth/invalid-email') {
                throw new Error('Email address is not valid');
            } else if (err.code === 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
                throw new Error('Email already existed');
            } else if (err.code === 'auth/network-request-failed') {
                throw new Error('Please check your connection');
            } else {
                throw new Error(
                    'An error occurred during sign up. Please try again later.'
                );
            }
        }
    };
```

**Sign-in with email/password**

```
const signInWithEmailAndPassword = async (email, password) => {
        try {
            const authInstance = getAuth();
            console.log('Auth instance', authInstance);
            return await emailPasswordSignIn(authInstance, email, password);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err.code);
            if (
                err.code === 'auth/user-not-found' ||
                err.code === 'auth/wrong-password'
            ) {
                throw new Error(
                    'Incorrect email or password. Please try again.'
                );
            } else if (err.code === 'auth/network-request-failed') {
                throw new Error('Please check your connection');
            } else if (err.code === 'auth/invalid-email') {
                throw new Error('Please provide valid email');
            } else {
                throw new Error(
                    'An error occurred during sign in. Please try again later.'
                );
            }
        }
    };
```

**Sign-in with google**

```
const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
        try {
            console.log('Google sign-in started');
            return await signInWithPopup(auth, googleProvider);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
            throw err;
        }
    };
```

I don't think I have changed any of my code. Please help me out, thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I have provided both the option of Google sign-in and email password sign-in. Both were working fine until yesterday.

What you're experiencing, is the default behavior even from the beginning, meaning that when the user signs in with a Google account, right after a successful authentication with email and password, the data is always overwritten in the Firebase Authentication. This means that Google credentials remain the default ones. This is happening for an obvious reason, a Google account is a more trusted source and hence this behavior.

To solve your problem, you need to [link those 2 accounts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking) in a single one, based on that email address. That's it.

Comment: And how do I link those accounts sir ? In Authentication settings, I can see that User account linking is selected as "Link accounts that use the same email"

Comment: See the documentation on [account linking](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking)

Comment: @Madhavmishra Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?